Firebase: Auth instance has already been used to make a network call
I have a mono repo project with my frontend and backend together.
I am trying to set up the Firebase emulator on both places where I do initializeApp
I suspect that setting up the emulator in both places makes them collide.
This is the frontend configuration
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...window.config
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Ensure no Firebase Auth calls are made before configuring the emulator
if (window.env === "emulator") {
  // Set the auth emulator BEFORE any auth calls are made
  firebase.auth().useEmulator("http://127.0.0.1:9099", { disableWarnings: true });

  // Set the Firestore emulator
  firebase.firestore().useEmulator("localhost", 8080);
}

// Now that the emulator is set, you can safely use the Firebase Auth instance
const auth = firebase.auth();

// Set up other authentication methods
const signInAnonymously = firebase;

If I don't run my backend everything works fine, and the part of my app that uses the frontend firebase does work perfectly.
This is the set up for the backend:
  const adminDB = require("firebase-admin");
  // Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK
  adminDB.initializeApp({
    credential: adminDB.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: config.firebaseConfig.databaseURL,
    databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
      uid: "service" // indicates that this is a service account and not an actual user
    }
  });

  const firestore = adminDB.firestore();

  // Check if using Firestore emulator
  if (process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST) {
    firestore.settings({
      host: process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST,
      ssl: false, // Emulator does not use SSL
      experimentalForceLongPolling: true, // Force HTTP/1 instead of gRPC
      useFetchStreams: false
    });
  }

Same way, if I try one of my endpoints using postman I get fetch data from my firebase emulator.
but at the time I open my dashboard view, were multiple request both from front and back are being made, I get the following error:
"Firebase: Auth instance has already been used to make a network call. Auth can no longer be configured to use the emulator. Try calling "connectAuthEmulator()" sooner. (auth/emulator-config-failed)."
Any ideas on how to aboard this?
Thanks in advance
Be able to have the firebase emulator running with auth and firestore locally on my app

can you tell me which firebase version are you using? in the frontend? I think this is the frontend problem on how you are calling useEmulator I haven't seen it being used like this. in my app I use
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
}

try moving auth variable before setting up emulator and then using that auth instance to connect to emulator

hey @AbdulRafayShaikh
I am using version "firebase": "^9.22.1".
I tried moving the auth before the if statement and setting the emulator with that instance and I am still getting the same issue.
Does it help to say that the first failed request is one calling my backend endpoint?

@AbdulRafayShaikh I am using the compat on firebase.
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
